# How to inherit variables in an inherited class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I need classes as shown below but I'm unable to override context in Child Class because signature is different

```
class BaseContext{}
class ChildContext:BaseContext{}

abstract class Base
{
    abstract BaseContext context{get;}
    ...
}

class Child : Base
{
    public override ChildContext context{get;}
    ...
}
```

Is there any better approach for this?

Comment: What error are you getting? The code you show here wouldn't even compile due to all the missing access modifiers.

Comment: You should have gotten an error that an `abstract` member cannot be `private`. Once you fix that (by making it `public`) this will work in sufficiently recent versions of C# (9 and up) that allow return type covariance.

Comment: This is not a variable. It is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) that should make your example work if you just fix the access modifiers to both be public or protected. But this feature is only available in .net 5 and later.

For older versions you can do add a [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) to create a new property with the same name:

```
public class BaseContext{}
public class ChildContext : BaseContext{}
public abstract class Base
{
    public BaseContext Context => ContextImpl;
    protected abstract BaseContext ContextImpl { get; }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public new ChildContext Context { get; }
    protected override BaseContext ContextImpl => Context;
}
```

This patter can be used to provide different levels of access depending on the reference type you have. The pattern is a bit easier to implement with interfaces since you can use [Explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to achieve the same thing, no need for a hidden abstract property.

```
public interface IBase
{
    BaseContext Context { get; }
}
public class Child : IBase
{
    BaseContext IBase.Context => Context;
    public  ChildContext Context { get; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can change the type of a read-only property. See: [Covariant returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks, I added a link and a note about .net versions.

Comment: This does not depend on the .NET version but on the C# version. You can add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to your project file to use the newest C# version in older .NET Versions. See: [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Sorry, no, it also depend on the runtime. Just tried it for .net 4.8, and the compiler complains about "Target runtime doesn't support covariant types in overrides"

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2022 and it works in .NET 4.8 projects. If you have an older VS Version then probably your runtime is older as well and doesn't support newer C# versions.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes not sure what you means. If I'm targeting .net 4.8 that will be the runtime. It should not depend on the visual studio version. And I can use other c# 9 features just fine. But it is odd if it works for you. Are you sure you have not added some runtime helper type?  Like the  `IsExternalInit` for the init-only feature?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes And while version discussions might be interesting, C# 9 is still not *supported* on earlier versions than .net 5. So I would still think it is useful to provide a workaround. I suspect that is the case for the OP, since his example should just work if the feature was available.

Comment: I tried a simple example, and it doesn't work for a .NET 4.8 target - the error is what you said it was. I believe that some support from the CLR is required for its implementation.,

Comment: The C# versions available depend on the version of the SDK which contains the runtime. Visual Studio installs a SDK, but you can install additional SDK's manually. I am using C# 11 in all my projects, including older .NET Framework projects. C# 11 features referred to as syntactic sugar work, the ones depending on the runtime or the Framework version don't. See Nick Chapsas's video [Using Latest C# Features in Any Old .NET Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgKa-tjnUMA).

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) here. For example:

```
// Make the base class generic
public abstract class Base<TContext> 
    where TContext : BaseContext // constrain the generic type to be a BaseContext
{
    public TContext context { get; }
}

public class Child : Base<ChildContext>
{
    // And here we no longer have to override the property
}
```

Comment: I will not be able to Base variable type here like Base base = new Child();

Comment: And why can you not do that?

Comment: I am getting compilation error, try Base<BaseContext> base = new Child();

Comment: Firstly that will not compile because you can't use `base` as a variable name. But why would you want to do that though?